# Snowflake connector python package not recognized

Tags: python, pip, jupyter-notebook, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Trying to import snowflake.connector:

```
import snowflake.connector

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In [1], line 1
----> 1 import snowflake.connector

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'snowflake.connector'; 'snowflake' is not a package
```

so I did:

```
%pip list
...

snowflake                  0.0.3               
snowflake-connector-python 2.8.0
snowflake-sqlalchemy       1.4.3  
...
```

I tried:

```
from snowflake import connector
```

and got

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In [5], line 1
----> 1 from snowflake import connector

ImportError: cannot import name 'connector' from 'snowflake' (/home/user/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/snowflake.py)
```

Comment: What about **pip install --upgrade snowflake-connector-python**?

Comment: @Sergiu I just tried that and apparently it is already the latest version as I only installed it a few days ago

Comment: Strange then, maybe your PYTHONPATH is not set properly?

Comment: 'print(sys.path)' returns '/home/user/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages' and 'pip install --upgrade snowflake-connector-python'
returns
'Requirement already up-to-date: snowflake-connector-python in ./.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (2.8.0)'

Comment: I think I see what the problem is: you have a file called **snowflake.py** in site-packages (probably coming from package **snowflake  0.0.3**, not sure what that one is for) and overwrites the actual Snowflake which should be in a folder called **snowflake** and then under you should have another folder called **connector**). Can you try removing from pip the package called snowflake and then see if you still have an issue?

Answer (score 7):

The answer as pointed out by @Sergiu was that I had a package called snowflake also installed. Solution:

```
pip3 uninstall snowflake
```